# No matching Method/Function for java.security.KeyStore.load(java.io.FileInputStream, string) found

Tags: java, xml, coldfusion, saml, cfml

I'm trying to use the method load() on a java.security.Keystore object in Coldfusion inside a cfscript.

Here's my code (not the full code, but enough to see the hierarchy of elements):

```
<cfoutput>

  <cfsavecontent variable="responseOpen">

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    ...

  </cfsavecontent>


  <cfxml variable="samlAssertionXML">

    ...

  </cfxml>


  <cfsavecontent variable="responseClose">

    </samlp:Response>

  </cfsavecontent>

  <cfscript>

     // 1) Injest the XML

     ...

     // 5) Keystore

     ksfile = CreateObject("Java", "java.io.File").init("Users/carl/keystore_test");

     inputStream = CreateObject("Java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init(ksfile);

     KeyStoreClass = CreateObject("Java" , "java.security.KeyStore");

     ks = KeyStoreClass.getInstance("JKS");

     ks.load(inputStream,"1221");

     ...

  </cfscript>

    ...

</cfoutput>
```

I'm getting an error that says:

> No matching Method/Function for
>   java.security.KeyStore.load(java.io.FileInputStream, string) found

on the line *ks.load(inputStream,"1221");*.

I made sure that inputStream is not null, and that inputStream is an object of type java.security.Keystore. I also made sure that the library java.security.Keystore is loaded. Proof of that is the code doesn't break before that line. The code is in a .cfm file.

Logging inputStream and ksfile, I got this:

- inputStream: the actual content of the keystore
- ksfile: /Users/carl/keystore_test

What could the problem possibly be?

Comment: dump your ksfile and inputStream objects to look for clues.

Comment: I already did, they look fine to me. I added the details in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [java.security.KeyStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), it looks like the `load()` method when called with an InputStream actually expects a character array (`char[]`), not a string. I would guess that is why you see the "No matching method" error. Could you try converting the string to a character array? E.g.:

```
password = "1221";
ks.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());
```

Comment: It worked! That's what any sane developer should do at first: Look at the function signature!! Thanks a lot jcberquist.